# How Facebook changes the Emoji from their symbols while chatting?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, frontend, web-frontend

[image: Initial Text when typing something in Facebook Chat Box]

[image: The moment you hit space it converts to this!]

First Image - Initial Text when typing something in Facebook Chat Box
Second Image - The moment you hit space it converts to this!

I have seen in developer console it is not the input box at all, they are using span and all with background-image to do it but how to actually combine it completely, to avoid any clutter whatsoever. I am attaching a link of codepen of what I did when pressing Enter key. But not able to do for the Space Bar. [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/abhilash27/pen/jGbPMO) Anything you guys can help. Thanks in advance. NOTE :- No external libraries and would prefer Javascript answer.

```
    var emojiContainer = {
                ":)" : "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/zeb/2/16/1f642.png",
                "<3" : "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/zed/2/16/2764.png"
            };
var chatDetailText = document.getElementById('chatDetailText');

chatDetailText.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
                console.log("Inside keypress event")
                var textEntered = chatDetailText.value;

                var keyPressed = e.which || e.keyCode;
                console.log(emojiContainer[this.value])

                if (keyPressed === 13){

                    console.log("inside keypress 13")
                if(emojiContainer[this.value]){
                    console.log("inside value found of enter")
                    var emojiImg = document.createElement("img");
                emojiImg.src = emojiContainer[this.value];

                document.getElementById('enterPressed').appendChild(emojiImg);
                document.getElementById('chatDetailText').value = '';   

            }else{
                console.log("value not found of enter")
                var divChatDetail = document.createElement('div');
                /*chatDetailSeperator.className = "aClassName";*/ //To add class name for div
                        divChatDetail.innerHTML = this.value;

                        document.getElementById('enterPressed').appendChild(divChatDetail);
                        document.getElementById('chatDetailText').value = '';   
            }
          }
            }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 ContentEditable attribute for div. 
here is just an example. Take care of cert position etc.

```js
var emojiContainer = {
    ":)" : "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/zeb/2/16/1f642.png",
    "<3" : "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/zed/2/16/2764.png"
   };
var chatDetailText = document.getElementById('chatDetailText');

chatDetailText.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
    console.log("Inside keypress event")
    var textEntered = chatDetailText.innerHTML;

    var keyPressed = e.which || e.keyCode;
    
        console.log(keyPressed)
        
    if (keyPressed === 32){
     
     var last_word = textEntered.split(" ");
          last_word = last_word[last_word.length-1];
          console.log(last_word);
       if(emojiContainer[last_word]){
        console.log("inside value found of enter")
        var emojiImg = "<img src='"+emojiContainer[last_word]+"' >";
          
            textEntered = textEntered.replace(last_word, emojiImg)
            
            chatDetailText.innerHTML = textEntered;
          

        }
       }
   }, false);
```

```html
<div id="enterPressed"></div>
  <div contenteditable="true"  id="chatDetailText" >edit this</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan for the above code. I updated the pen with this, but now it takes the pointer to the start of the line plus this works only once like if I type multiple :) it does not work, does it has something to do with keypress event. And this will not even let the user submit the message by pressing enter key or I'll have to keep different functions for both which I thought can be avoided. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I got it done, thanks to Zeeshan for helping me with contenteditable. Do update if you have any improvisations.

```
var emojiContainer = {
                ":)" : "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/zeb/2/16/1f642.png",
                "<3" : "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/emoji.php/v9/zed/2/16/2764.png"
            };

var chatDetailText = document.getElementById('chatDetailText');

chatDetailText.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  //to perform the action based on pressing space bar (32) or enter (13).
  var keydown = e.which || e.keyCode;

  //to get the pointer location and modify to place to the end if needed
  var selectionInfo = getSelectionTextInfo(this); 

  //to get the complete text extered by the user.
  var input = chatDetailText.innerHTML;

  //to cover the cases in which user enters <3 and gets interpreted as &lt
  var textEntered = decodeHtml(input);

  //To split the text entered and to get the location of the emoji for conversion
  var last_word = textEntered.split(/\s{1}/);

  //After splitting contains the emoji and now can be accessed.
  last_word = last_word[last_word.length-1];

  //space bar is pressed and the smiley is just inserted
  if (keydown === 32 && selectionInfo.atEnd){
    //if the emoji is available in our database, it'll replace the same using the Facebook url which is currently used.
    if(emojiContainer[last_word]){

      var emojiImg = "<img src='"+emojiContainer[last_word]+"' >";

      textEntered = textEntered.replace(last_word, emojiImg);
      chatDetailText.innerHTML = textEntered;

      elemIterate = document.getElementById('chatDetailText');//This is the element to move the caret to the end of
      setEndOfContenteditable(elemIterate);
    }
    //Enter key is pressed after typing the emoji
  }else if (keydown === 13) {
    // To avoid extra line insertion in div.
    e.preventDefault();
    //if the emoji is available in our database, it'll replace the same using the Facebook url which is currently used. 
    if(emojiContainer[last_word]){

      var emojiImg = document.createElement("img");
      emojiImg.src = emojiContainer[last_word];

      var spanChatElement = document.createElement("span");
      var precedingChatContent = textEntered.split(/\s{1}/);

      precedingChatContent.pop(); //To pop the last smiley found

      if(precedingChatContent.length !=0){
        precedingChatContent = precedingChatContent.join(" ");
        spanChatElement.innerHTML = precedingChatContent;
        document.getElementById('enterPressed').appendChild(spanChatElement);
      }

      document.getElementById('enterPressed').appendChild(emojiImg);
      document.getElementById('chatDetailText').innerHTML = '';

    }else{
      //If no Smiley found, just the plain text it'll automatically display the text in a div
      var divChatElement = document.createElement('div');
      //chatDetailSeperator.className = "aClassName"; To add class name for div
      divChatElement.innerHTML = textEntered;

      document.getElementById('enterPressed').appendChild(divChatElement);
      document.getElementById('chatDetailText').innerHTML = ''; 
    }
  }
}, false);

function decodeHtml(html) {
  var textAreaElement = document.createElement("textarea");
  textAreaElement.innerHTML = html;
  return textAreaElement.value;
}
//To send the pointer to the end of the div.
function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement){
  var range,selection;
  if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
  {
    range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is like the selection but invisible)
    range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
    range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
    selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
    selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
    selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
  }
  else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
  { 
    range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is like the selection but invisible)
    range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
    range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
    range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
  }
}
//To check if it is at the end.
function getSelectionTextInfo(contentEditableElement) {
  var atEnd = false;
  var selectionRange, testRange;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    var windowSelection = window.getSelection();
    if (windowSelection.rangeCount) {
      selectionRange = windowSelection.getRangeAt(0);
      testRange = selectionRange.cloneRange();

      testRange.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
      testRange.setStart(selectionRange.endContainer, selectionRange.endOffset);
      atEnd = (testRange.toString() == "");
    }
  }else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    selectionRange = document.selection.createRange();
    testRange = selectionRange.duplicate();

    testRange.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
    testRange.setEndPoint("StartToEnd", selectionRange);
    atEnd = (testRange.text == "");
  }
  return { atEnd: atEnd };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the line `if (keyPressed === 13){` to `if (keyPressed === 32){` in your codepen link. And to stop that from posting the comment, you just need to add another function for `if (keypressed === 13)`.